# Euclidean geometry theorem proving complexity

Tags: time-complexity, computational-geometry

Euclidean geometry is complete, so the problem of determining whether a statement $A$ is provable is computable. Do we know its time complexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common to prove the decidability of first-order Euclidean geometry by encoding the language of Euclidean geometry into the language of real closed fields and then showing that the latter is decidable. A singly-exponential space upper bound on [deciding the first-order theory of real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Complexity_of_deciding) was proven in [Ben-Or, Kozen, and Reif (1986)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000086900292). This implies a doubly-exponential time upper bound.

I believe this is the best known complexity for the decision problem for general first-order sentences in the language of real closed fields. However, I am not sure whether deciding real closed fields is *equivalent* (bidirectionally) to deciding Euclidean geometry, since a typical encoding of (say) the language of [Tarski's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms) into the language of real closed fields only uses a small subset of the possible polynomials. So maybe first-order Euclidean geometry can be decided with lower complexity than this. It is at least PSPACE-hard, since [TQBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_quantified_Boolean_formula) is easily encoded into first-order Euclidean geometry.